# Angular2 "override" specific form control in a form group

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm wondering if it's possible to extend/override a FormGroup structure with Angular2.

I've got a FormGroup :

```
this.formgroup1 = this.fb.group({
  control1 : '', // the field will be a select
  control2 : '',
  control3 : ''
})
```

And I've to build another FormGroup, which is almost the same but with only one different control like this :

```
this.formgroup2 = this.fb.group({
  control0 : '', // the field will be an input
  control2 : '',
  control3 : '' 
})
```

Is there a way to build the formgroup2 according to the formgroup1 stucture? My aim is just not repeating the same code as above.

Thanks !

Comment: Well the form control doesn't care if it is an input or select. Form control just accepts a value, it doesn't care how or where it comes from.